# In Chrome driver selenium we are getting error as Non secure data:,

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium2library

IN chrome browser when we open application we are getting **Non Secure data:,**
[screenshotLINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzWWQ.png)

i have tried different solution along with below code still no success!!

String chromeDriverPath = projectLocationPath + "\Resources\chromedriver.exe";

```
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("test-type");
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
            options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary",chromeDriverPath);  
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); 
            webdriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);  
            driver.get(url);
```

i have added all required capabilities

**URL - https://tsetigndev123.dev.hfgh.com**

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Downloading the latest chromedriver.exe from [URL](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and replacing it with the old one fixed the problem for me.

The underlying error message i had was : "cannot get automation extension".

Comment: I was trying to solve this issue since last 4 hours. It never crossed my mind to update a chrome driver, because my code was working couple of months ago as intended. It is just today it started behaving weirdly. This is what was happening. I run 5 browser windows in parallel, but only one window that is in focus works automatically. Other windows do their job when I click on them and make it active. Updating a chrome driver to latest version solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've disabled security and then tried to access a secure URL.  If you mean to access the web site without security, change the url to http://tsetigndev123dev.hfgh.com (leaving out the "s" in "https"